# Calculating total count for a start and stop clock using c#

Tags: c#

In my application i have a start and stop clock for sending some remainder. whenever the clock starts and stops, it will identify the start and stop date and it will eliminate all the public holidays and weekends. I had succeed in eliminating public holidays and weekends. Now my issue is i need to loop through all the working days and should identify whether the clock starts at AM or PM for identifying whether the clock covers a full day or a half day. There is Count  variable which is initialised as 0.5 and increment after every half day(After every AM and PM). No idea how to loop through every half day of the working days and find total count.

Removed all Weekends and Holidays.

```cs
public double ElapseDays(string caseNo, string DatePart)
{
    double count = 0;
    double weekEndsCount;
    Boolean excludeWeekends = true;

    using (var db = new EMSDEntities())
    {
        var q = (from a in db.SY_HOLIDAYS
                 orderby a.HLD_DATE
                 select new HolidayListViewModel
                 {
                    HolidayDate = a.HLD_DATE,

                 }).ToList();

        for (DateTime index = '01/07/2019'; index <= '03/07/2019'; index = index.AddDays(1))
        {
            bool excluded = false;
            if (excludeWeekends && index.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && index.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {               
                for (int i = 0; i < q.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (index.Date.CompareTo(q[i].HolidayDate) == 0)
                    {
                        excluded = true;
                        break;
                    }
                } 
            }
            if (!excluded)
            {
                count = count + 0.5;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Basic HTML Table</h2>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>start_date</th>
    <th>end_date</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>01/07/2019 PM</td>
    <td>03/07/2019 PM</td>
  </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The count should come as 2.5, Cause clock started on (01/07/2019) PM(Half day). so it will initialise count as 0.5 and stops at (03/07/2019)PM(full day)

Comment: Hi, what exactly is you question?

Comment: Only the start and end dates can be half days. So loop through all the days greater than start and less than end. Then add on the start and end as one or half according to the AM/PM logic.